# HTML page with graphs and charts through PYTHON

Tags: python, html, pandas, matplotlib

I am attaching my code below, I want to majorly create a HTML based output page with graphs and tables formatted perfectly, but I am facing issue that the HTML page does not have any image when I load it, why so? Can someone help me rectify the entire code?
I want an easy way to create a dashboard from python which has an output file of HTML with all formatting of graphs, tables as required.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, Spacer
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import mpld3

# Function to format the x-axis ticks
def format_month_year(x):
    return x.strftime('%b %Y')

# Your existing code for the document setup
pdf_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Quant_Dashboard/tradesheet_report.pdf"
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_path, pagesize=A4)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

kpi_values = {
    'Total Days in Trade': {'lower': 'NA', 'upper': 'NA','strategy':str(total_days_in_trade)},
    'Max Absolute Drawdown':{'lower':'NA', 'upper':'20%', 'strategy':str(max_absolute_drawdown)},
    'Cumulative Return': {'lower': 'NA', 'upper': 'NA','strategy':str(cumulative_return) + '%'},
    'CAGR':{'lower': 'NA', 'upper': 'NA','strategy':str(round(cagr,2))}

}

kpi_table_data = [
    ['KPI', 'Lower Bound', 'Upper Bound', 'Strategy Statistics'],
    ['Risk Free Rate','0%','0%','0%'],
    ['Cumulative Return', kpi_values['Cumulative Return']['lower'], kpi_values['Cumulative Return']['upper'],kpi_values['Cumulative Return']['strategy']],
    ['Max Absolute Drawdown', kpi_values['Max Absolute Drawdown']['lower'], kpi_values['Max Absolute Drawdown']['upper'],kpi_values['Max Absolute Drawdown']['strategy']],
    ['CAGR', kpi_values['CAGR']['lower'], kpi_values['CAGR']['upper'],kpi_values['CAGR']['strategy']]
]

# Modify kpi_table_style to highlight values beyond bounds
kpi_table_style = [
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.grey),
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.beige),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),  # Add grid lines
    # Add styles to highlight values beyond bounds
    ('BACKGROUND', (2, 1), (2, -1), colors.lightcoral),
    ('BACKGROUND', (3, 1), (3, -1), colors.lightgreen),
]

# Create KPI Table
kpi_table = Table(kpi_table_data, colWidths=130, rowHeights=30, style=kpi_table_style)
content = [kpi_table]

# Add space between KPI table and plots
content.append(Spacer(1, 20))

# Add plots to the PDF
plot_paths = []

# Function to save plot as image
def save_plot_as_image(plt, path):
    plt.savefig(path)
    plt.close()

# Plot Daily Active Returns
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
daily_active_returns = df['Daily_Profit'].dropna()
ax = daily_active_returns.plot(color='skyblue', linestyle='-', marker='o', markersize=4)
ax.set_title('Daily Active Returns', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Daily Active Return', fontweight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
daily_active_returns_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Quant_Dashboard/daily_active_returns.png"
save_plot_as_image(plt, daily_active_returns_path)
plot_paths.append(daily_active_returns_path)

# Monthly Profits
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
monthly_profits = df.resample('M', on='ETM')['PF'].sum()
ax = monthly_profits.plot(kind='bar', color='gold')
ax.set_title('Monthly Profits', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Month', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Profit', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xticklabels([format_month_year(date) for date in monthly_profits.index], rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
monthly_profits_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Quant_Dashboard/monthly_profits.png"
save_plot_as_image(plt, monthly_profits_path)
plot_paths.append(monthly_profits_path)

# Create HTML content
html_content = []

# Add KPI table to HTML content
buffer = BytesIO()
pdf_doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
elements = [kpi_table]
pdf_doc.build(elements)
table_img = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
table_img_base64 = base64.b64encode(table_img).decode('utf-8')
html_content.append(f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{table_img_base64}"/>')

# Add space between KPI table and plots
html_content.append("<br>")

# Add plots to HTML content
for plot_path in plot_paths:
    html_content.append(f'<img src="{plot_path}" width="800" height="600"/>')
    html_content.append("<br>")

# Save the HTML content to a file
html_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Quant_Dashboard/tradesheet_report.html"
with open(html_path, "w") as html_file:
    html_file.write("".join(html_content))
```

Comment: HTML ouput, I recommend `pybars`.  https://github.com/wbond/pybars3
+ [Table and Chart Subplots in Python](https://plotly.com/python/table-subplots/)